# Flutter: Slider in Dismissable does not work

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have an audio player that is a child of a Dismissable in a ReorderableListView.

The volume control (a Slider) does not slide, instead the Dismissable slide to dismiss is activated.

How do I suppress the Dismissable action when operating the Slider?

Note that the Dismissable is far removed from the audio player in the widget build hierarchy.

Comment: Can you include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Just too many layers, unfortunately, to put up a minimal code. For now, I am using Riverpod to notify and disable Dismissable when there is a slider on a widget... a bad design, I know...

Comment: have you found a viable solution? this combination worked well prior to flutter 3, and on iphone this does not happen

Comment: @Develocode777, no, I just stopped looking for one after two days of struggle. As said before, I remove the dismissible when the widget has sliders. In my code I have a manual delete icon as well, so for now I am moving on...

Comment: its fixed in 3.0.2